# When I try to get data from MySQL database to jtable same data repeats in the jtable

Tags: vector, jtable

```
try {
            Connection getConnection = getDatabase_Connection.getConnection();
            Statement getsStatement = getConnection.createStatement();
            ResultSet getResultSet = getsStatement.executeQuery("Select * from ap_database.ap_details");
            DefaultTableModel setDefaultTableModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
            Vector setVector = new Vector();
            while (getResultSet.next()) {
```

> Here I set my data from resultset to my vector

```
                setVector.add(getResultSet.getString("s_no"));
                setVector.add(getResultSet.getString("ap_rm"));
                setVector.add(getResultSet.getString("ap_serial"));
                setVector.add(getResultSet.getString("ap_gname"));
                setVector.add(getResultSet.getString("ap_ci"));
                setVector.add(getResultSet.getString("ap_co"));
                setVector.add(getResultSet.getString("ap_edate"));
                setVector.add(getResultSet.getString("ap_issuedp"));
                setVector.add(getResultSet.getString("ap_remark"));
                setVector.add(getResultSet.getString("ap_status"));
```

> In this I add my vector into the DefaultTableModel

```
                setDefaultTableModel.addRow(setVector);  
                jTable1.setModel(setDefaultTableModel);
            }
```

> After that first row of my data repeats number of rows that i have in my resultset.

```
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
```

Comment: What else would you expect if you use a `while` to go over the returned results? Did you try to modify your query to return only the one row you expect?

Comment: Yes, when i try to get specific row it appears, but if i try to get multiple rows it repeats the the first row data.

Answer (score 0):

first of all need to download rs2xml.jar file and add to your project folder and write this code after your resultset

```
DefaultTableModel setDefaultTableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(getResultSet));
```

It will work.